# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to upgrade Cucumber from 1.2.5 to 4.2.0 version, i have tried to add all the dependencies based on the info got from this page: [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java/4.2.0) but still getting this kind of error.

Do i need to add another dependency?

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:173)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.pluginClass(PluginFactory.java:165)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.getPluginClass(PluginFactory.java:222)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isStepDefinitionReporterName(PluginFactory.java:205)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptions.java:357)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:159)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:90)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:85)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:23)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:84)
at com.TMG.subs.testrunner.ExtendedCucumberRunner.<init>(ExtendedCucumberRunner.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.formatter.Reporter

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: This interface has been removed. Ur plugin needs to implement EventListener or ConcurrentEventListener or other interfaces. Or the Plugin interface directly. Check the source of Plugin for the other interfaces. Refer to HTMLFormatter plugin in source as code for plugins have been totally revamped.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it turned out that  those two dependencies were throwing the  erorr,so i wiped them out because we don't use it anymore in our solution.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>

    Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("src/test/resources/extent-config.xml"));
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("user", System.getProperty("user.name"));
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("os", "Mac OSX");
```